# C Structure Linked List Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, list, linked-list, fault

I am learning linked lists in C and I am having a problem with my delete function. A segmentation fault occurs at the line:

`while(current1 != NULL && (current1->next->data != d))`

```
void delete(int d)
{
    struct list * current1 = head; 
    struct list * current2;

    if (len() == 0)
    { //prtError("empty");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (head -> data == d)
    { 
        head = head -> next;
    }

    //Check if last node contains element
    while (current1->next->next != NULL)
        current1 = current1->next;
    if(current1->next->data == d)
            current1->next == NULL; 

    current1 = head; //move current1 back to front */

    while(current1 != NULL && (current1->next->data != d))
        current1 = current1 -> next; 

    current2 = current1 -> next;
    current1 -> next = current2 -> next; 
}
```

Comment: I fixed the problem with the NULL bu now I am getting a fault at the last line current1 -> next = curren2 -> next

Comment: I edited my answer to explain with you are getting this error now.

Answer (score 1):

You are making sure there's at least one element at `current1` with your test `current1 != NULL` so `current1->next` is guaranteed to work, but it might return `NULL` itself causing `current1->next->data` to crash as it tries to get data from the *next* element.

Answer (score 1):

At this line you don't know if `current1->next` is NULL or not. If it is `NULL` and you try to access `current1->next->data` you will end with a `segmentation fault`.

You have two solution to fix your loop :

```
while(current1 != NULL && (current1->data != d))
    //                             ^^^^^^^
    current1 = current1 -> next;
```

Or

```
if ( current1 != NULL )
    while (current1->next != NULL && (current1->next->data != d))
        //         ^^^^^^
        current1 = current1 -> next;
```

But in the second case you have to be sure that at the first loop `current1 != NULL`.

**To answer to the comment :**

It is the same error, you don't know if `current1` is `NULL` or not and you try to access to the `next` element, you have two things to do :

- First you have to be sure that `current1` is not `NULL` before trying to reach the `next`
- And just after you have to be sure that `current2` is not `NULL` too.

You have two possibilies (easy to do) :

```
if ( NULL != current1 )
{
    current2 = current1->next;

    if ( NULL != current2 )
        current1->next = current2->next;
}
```

Or

```
if ( NULL != current1 && NULL != current1->next )
{
    current2 = current1->next;
    current1->next = current2->next;
}
```

Both will work well. Choose the one you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

In the line that you told us had the error, you're never checking whether or not `current1->next` is `NULL` or not. At some point in your program, `current1->next` *is* `NULL`, and so you are trying to dereference the address `0`. At that point, the code is equivalent to `((struct list *)0)->data`. Thus the segmentation fault.